# Loop that checks if a file exists in the directory and if it does adds an integer to the file name

Tags: loops, rust

```
let plz_work = String::from("edit");

while fs::try_exists(plz_work + &edit_num.to_string()).is_ok(){

}
```

Basically I need to convert a string to an &str. I would've just added the integer to an &str but it has to be a string, I think. I keep getting errors. How do I get the value out of the scope?

My program needs to create it's working folder so it knows which folder has the things it's going to manipulate.

My first language is C++. Even though I'm relatively inexperienced I decided to try Rust and got stuck here.

Comment: What's wrong with `format!("...")` here? Doing this with string addition seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: @tadman format?

Comment: Why phrase your suggestion that way, as if presuming the OP considered and rejected `format!`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm just asking. Sometimes there's constraints that aren't specified.

Comment: I think I might understand how format!() works but an example would be helpful.

Comment: @tadman I feel stupid now but it works to my knowledge, at least the error message is gone. I hope that my code at least works at the moment because I have such ugly functions I think i'ma have to learn OOP

Comment: The high-level overview is [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html), but the real magic is in the [formatter options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) where you can easily zero-pad, etc. C++ now has an analogous [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).

Comment: I haven't used C++ in a min, I'd call myself a beginner at best even though I learned my programming concepts there, knowing that there is just a format keyword is somewhat reassuring, that there was just something out there that fixed my incredibly specific issue.

Comment: If you've got a working solution, pop in a self-answer to help close this out. What you're working with here isn't an uncommon problem when picking up Rust.

Comment: ok my apologies, I don't use stack overflow often